# How i can remove these artifacts in blender?

Tags: artifacts

Hey blender community,

i creating a emboss logo. Unfortunately after i used the modifier solidify i got some artifacts. Do you know how to remove these artifacts?

Thank you so much in advance for any help ;)[image]
[image]

Here is my blender file:

[image]

Comment: First make sure that you have a relatively clean topology and also try recalculating the normals. If that doesn't work, please share your file. Use blend-exchange and paste the generated link into the question by editing it.

Comment: Hey Kalaakaar,

first i would like to thank you for your help. I really appreciate your time :)

Yes i have a clean topology and i also recalculated the normals

Here is my blender file: 
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=s0KMJQns" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/s0KMJQns/)

Thank you

Comment: The mesh of the letter "T" is bad. It as overlapping edges/faces. This causes the problems with the modifier. The topology of the "N" and "L" is also not ideal. They have big n-gons. On top of this, you use a *Boolean* modifier to emboss the text. This creates a "chaotic" topology, which is fine if you don't want to deform the mesh or use more modifiers.

Comment: Hey Blunder,

thank you so much for your help.
I don't want to deform the mesh or use other modifier. I only use solidify, decimate and boolean.

After I used the modifier solidify to increase the thickness to 0.5 the artifacts ("T" overlapping edges) appeared.
How can i fix the edges of the letter "T" and the Topology of "N" and "L"?

Answer (score 0):

The topology of your letters looks clean but it is not ideal polygon-wise. There are a lot of ngons (That's faces that have more than 4 vertices). Especially the letter "T" is messed up. It also has zero-faces with no area and overlapping edges. This creates the issues with the *Solidify* modifier.

If you remove the emboss effect by deleting the vertices that the *Solidify* modifier has added then you will see in *Object* mode that the outline is corrupt. There is an extra line in the outline **(1)**. If you back to *Edit* mode an move the corner vertex **(3)** of the "T" then you see there are more faces and edges than you would expect **(3)** + **(4)**:
[image: bad letter T]

Delete the extra edges (<kbd>X</kbd>) in *Edit* mode, subdivide the upper edge (menu) to create extra vertices and connect them (<kbd>F</kbd>) so that the letter is created by 4 faces with only 4 vertices each (quads) **(1)**. Then the extra line in Object mode **(2)** and the issue **(3)** with the modifier is gone.

Make the sure the normals all point outwards (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Normals > Recalculate Outside*)

[image: fixed letter T]

The ngons can be replaced by quads in the similar way.

**Ian McGlasham** has a great tutorial series about [Advanced Text Retopology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC-qyGzRyeQ&list=PLoSyNsQF2hFDX8gsIhcnl2j2gvhNkhPZk). It works also great for imported SVGs, logos, cloth sewing patterns, etc.